# Change join condition based on a condition - Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, join

assume we have two tables.

```
TabA(Acol1,Acol2,Acol3)
TabB(Bcol1,Bcol2.Ccol3)
```

Requirement is like, join two tables on Acol1,Bcol1 and if Acol3='C' then join based on Acol2=Bcol2 in addition to above join. Can we make this in single SQL query ? Is join is record wise or table wise ?

One solution I can get to is using Union, but I dont think this will be a optimized one. Any other solutions ?

Another solution I figured

```
SELECT A.*,B.* FROM TabA A
         INNER JOIN TabB B ON A.Acol1 = B.BCol1 
         and case when A.Acol3='C' then A.ACol2 else '1' end = 
             case when A.Acol3='C' then B.BCol2 else '1' end ;
```

Any other solution without case and Union ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please edit your question and provide sample data and desired results.  It isn't clear what you are trying to do.

Comment: Could you just include an `or` in your join, or are you after something more?  e.g. `on (a.col1 = b.col1) and (a.col2 != 'C' or a.col2=b.col2)`.

Answer (score 0):

Hmmm, after thinking about the question, I think you might just want a complicated `on` clause:

```
select a.*, b.*
from tabA a join
     tabB b
     on a.col1 = b.col1 and
        (a.col3 <> 'C' or a.col2 = b.col2);
```

Note:  the above assumes that `a.col2` is not null (that condition is easily included if needed).

You may need to work out some examples by hand to see that the `or` method is equivalent to the `case` statement.

Comment: @Adriana . . . It is essentially the same query.  Just the `on` condition changes from `a.col2` to `a.col3`.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to join on TabA.col2 only when it is 'C' then in those case, TabB.col2 will also be 'C', as you are already joining from col1. So your output will be same which you get just by first join.

```
 select a.*, b.* from tabA a join tabB b
 on a.col1=b.col1
```

This should give you the same output anytime. Try creating a different scenario on values of 'C'. The result will always be a subset of your first join result.